# Cannot create an API controller with actions using Entity Framework for SQL Server database view

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am developing a Web API using ASP.NET Core 3.1.2 with Visual Studio 2019 v16.5.2.

My problem is when I try to create a controller for a database view model class, I get this message after scaffolding:

[image: after scaffolding when I try to create API controller using Entity Framework]

What I tried: I tried to redesign my database view to be like this (I mean using ISNULL with id column) but I get same result when creating the controller:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(dbo.CoSections.id, 0) AS Id, dbo.CoClasses.name, 
    dbo.CoSections.Code, dbo.CoSections.MaxStudents, 
    dbo.CoSections.CurrentStudents, dbo.CoSections.Completed, 
    dbo.CoSections.Year, dbo.CoSections.descreption
FROM
    dbo.CoSections 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.CoClasses ON dbo.CoSections.Class_ID = dbo.CoClasses.id
```

I also tried to put `Key` attribute above of id field in the model class, but that did not work either.

This problem is happening with views only - not tables.

Thanks in advance for all ideas and help

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks friend, but it's already existing because I created the Models using scaffold-DbContext instruction using Package Manager Console. but I cannot know how I can get the result of View after running the API .. what should I write in URL ? also I need to know if I can get the result of the View using HTTP request from Angular (front end) . Thanks

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Solved by creating Controller manually .. but I have a lot of views and I need to use this way to create a controller: right click on controllers folder -> add -> controller -> API controller with actions, using Entity Framework. to scaffold my Model and create the 5 HTTP verbs to communicate with front end easily. Is this possible?